# PHP generated div boxes which has included php files as content but first 2 divs empty

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
$dir    = 'folder/';
$files = scandir($dir);
$count=0;
foreach($files as $file){
        $count++;
            echo '<div style="float:left; margin: 0 0 10px 10px;border:1px solid       #50A4AB;  width:200px"><br>';
            if(strpos($file,".php")){
                            include($dir.$file);
                                }
                echo '</div><br>';
                if($count==7){echo'<div style="clear:both;></div><br>';}
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

First 2 divs empty and disordered, how to do proper div boxes with included php files,
thanks in advance for any help..

Comment: check for readable files with is_readable($dir.$file);

Comment: @mohammadfalahat thanks I am not sure if i put the code in good place and combination but this time i get no one included in div boxes

Comment: is this all of your code? did you close out the </body></html>

Comment: @DaviChenung thanks David but i just forget it to add here now i have edited my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting directory to this:

```
$dir    = '/folder';
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue might be with your echo statements, you need to escape the quotes.

Try this:

```
echo "<div style=\"float:left; margin: 0 0 10px 10px;border:1px solid #50A4AB;  width:200px \"><br>";

if($count==7){echo"<div style=\"clear:both;\"></div><br>";}
```

Comment: Hey David thanks i have modificated my code as you suggest but first 2 div boxes still empty :(

Answer (score 0):

if the include are failing you can understand with die() function

```
include($dir.$file) or die('error in including '.$file);
```

and if you don't get any errors so your files are empty or not readable.

Comment: now i get error Warning: include(1) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/denemeler4/index.php on    actually i dont have any file wich name is 1 in related file folder..

Comment: please echo $dir.$file before including

Comment: thank you Mohammad, but no array content to see if i done, what you said correctly